# Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Help me out, Im using localhost and getting this error whenever i fill out the form and click on submit button

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''aw-tech'.'contact' (name, email, phone, question) VALUES
>   ('prince', 'khan@princ' at line 1

**My PHP CODE SQL**

```
mysql_select_db("aw-tech", $con);

$sql = "INSERT INTO 'aw-tech'.'contact' (name, email, phone, question) 
            VALUES ('$_POST[name]', '$_POST[email]', 
                    '$_POST[phone]', '$_POST[question]')";
```

Comment: You need to use backticks around the names of tables (and columns) - you're using apostrophes.

Comment: watch out for sql injection....

Comment: @andrewsi in fact he doesn't need any kind of quotation here.

Comment: @Plasmarob - that's actually a fine error message.  The syntax is wrong.  It says to the right of (before) the quoted statement... which is exactly where the error is.  So... what someone would do is look up the syntax for an `insert` statement and see how their code compares.

Comment: **Warning:** you're using [a **deprecated** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php). You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the you use straight single quotes (') instead of backticks (`).
You should write

```
"INSERT INTO `aw-tech`.`contact` ...
```

instead of

```
"INSERT INTO 'aw-tech'.'contact' ...
```